# How do I send a POST with boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, iis-8

From the [Boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/networking/iostreams.html), you can send a GET through an iostream quite easily:

```
ip::tcp::iostream stream;
stream.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(60));
stream.connect("www.boost.org", "http");
stream << "GET /LICENSE_1_0.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n";
stream << "Host: www.boost.org\r\n";
stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
stream.flush();
std::cout << stream.rdbuf();
```

When I modify the above to connect to my IIS server, it works fine. The problem comes in when I try to send a POST to my server. Then I get the error message "HTTP Error 400. The request verb is invalid."

Various online discussions make it seem that the problem is with separator characters in headers, but removing all question marks fixed nothing.

Is there something that I'm missing here? [This forum discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/boost-list/cP6woPkQ1tw) makes it look like POSTing with an iostream should be doable. Google hasn't been much use since post is such an overloaded word online.

Edit - here's an example of my POST. With a GET, the server will pick it up and the handler will complain that it wants a POST (as it should).

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream;

stream.connect("myurl.com", "http");
stream << "POST /.api/api.svc/objects/723aa707-4978-4062-bcc6-67b05783c4ec/comments/add\r\n";
stream << "Host: myurl.com\r\n";
stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
stream << "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8\r\n";
stream << "Content-Length: 51\r\n";
stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

stream << "message=%3Cp%3EHello%3C%2Fp%3E";
stream.flush();
std::cout << stream.rdbuf();
```

Comment: What does your `POST` code look like?

Comment: I edited the question with an example.

Comment: One thing that I notice is that you don't include the HTTP version of the request at the end of the POST line.

Comment: @Omaha is right, adding the HTTP version is required. The POST failing on my server seems to be a problem on the IIS side of things. For anyone in a similar situation, posttestserver.com is a very useful resource.

Comment: And it turns out that the rest of the problem was due to me changing the content without updating the Content-Length. Embarrassing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Omaha spotted, the POST request is invalid. The POST line should look something like:

```
stream << "POST /.api/api.svc/objects/723aa707-4978-4062-bcc6-67b05783c4ec/comments/add  HTTP/1.0\r\n"
```

to be a valid HTTP request. See [HTTP/1.1: Request](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1)